# Software linux raid using physical passthrough disks

Tags: linux, raid, vmware-esxi, software-raid, mdadm

I'm using Vmware ESXI and I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/Hengjie/1520114890bebe8f805d337af4b3a064) guide to pass through 2 physical disks for a raid 1 array. If I set up an mdadm software raid using these two physical passthrough disks will something go wrong? Also if I take one of these disks and plug it individually into a machine to backup files in case of failure will all the files be accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about building-up RAID array *inside a VM*, then it doesn't make much sense in terms of efficiency compared to having built that RAID on hardware node itself. It'd work but will involve more overhead because VM would update both disks separately and crossing "virtualisation boundaries" has own penalties. Again — just 2 disks doesn't mean you'd lose a lot, but for bigger arrays it could be noticeable pretty soon.

It's rarely making any sense in terms of flexibility and overall management of resources too.

Comment: I'm doing it with physical disks, my motherboard raid is disgusting and I don't have a raid card. All of my things run on ESXi and the drives are storage drives for a network share, I passed them through to a VM so I could access it as a network share. Its just Raid 1 since I care about redundancy over speed for that.

Comment: it's not relevant. I've asked if your building the RAID inside a VM.

Comment: yes I am, what else would I build it in?

Comment: Already explained — on the host itself. If ESXi doesn't have any tools for that, even "disgusting BIOS"' RAID could be better

Comment: By disgusting bios raid, I mean raid that only works in windows and requires a driver to be installed. For raid 1 what is the benefit of hardware? And ESXi has no tools for raid.

Comment: Well, to cut the corners: it's not as optimal as having RAID on the node but if you can't have it on the node, 2 disks RAID is bearable configuration for running in a VM.

Comment: @Moptop how did you do it? is it working inside VM with mdadm? performance ok? I am usin xcp-ng and want to use raid inside VM to expose it as NFS.

Comment: @hrvoj3e It ended up working fine for a while but the speeds weren't very fast and I ended up just installing regular Linux on the host with ZFS raid and QEMU with virt-manager and X-Server. This is just what I ended up doing. If you really want to use the hypervisor for it I would recommend getting a hardware raid card or just doing the mdadm thing I did previously. It works fine

Comment: huh. When answer isn't marked as accepted but de-facto it is.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine. Linux sees them as block devices and treats them as such. Just make sure you use a journalling filesystem.

If you manually try read data from a degraded array this should work, however depending in the disk layout and where metadata is  there may be a few hoops to jump through. It would be better to use partitions for mdadm rather then whole disks.